# Importing wallets to cardano-node

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, cardano-node, cardano-address

when I'm upgrading `cardano-node` and `cardano-wallet`, I saved the wallets (.sqlite, sqlite-shm, sqlite,wal files) created in the node (cardano-node/data folder). After upgrading to the new node 1.35.3 I paste the wallet files to the same directory, but the `cardano-wallet wallets list` command isn't able to recognize the files. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `cardano-wallet` is pointing to the right database path by passing `--database /path/to/your/db`

Generally speaking you should manage `cardano-wallet` in a 'daemonized' manner (e.g. using systemd), this way you update your binary and restart the daemon, leaving the configuration untouched.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the mnemonic and the passphrase of the wallet, you can recover it with cardano-wallet.